# Concat values of array with same key

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation

I want to concat values of array with same key
Example:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => XYZ
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => B
        [1] => ABC
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => LMN
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => B
        [1] => PQR
    )
)
```

Expected output:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => XYZ,LMN
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => B
        [1] => ABC,PQR
    )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution uses the PHP function [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
// The input array you posted in the question
$input = array(
    array('A', 'XYZ'),
    array('B', 'ABC'),
    array('A', 'LMN'),
    array('B', 'PQR'),
);

// Reduce the array to a new array that contains the data aggregated as you need
$output = array_reduce(
    // Process each $item from $input using a callback function
    $input,
    // The callback function processes $item; the partial result is $carry
    function (array $carry, array $item) {
        // Extract the key into a variable
        $key = $item[0];
        // If the key was encountered before
        // then a partial entry already exists in $carry
        if (isset($carry[$key])) {
            // Append the desired value to the existing entry
            $carry[$key][1] .= ','.$item[1];
        } else {
            // Create a new entry in $carry (copy $item to key $key for quick retrieval)
            $carry[$key] = $item;
        }
        // Return the updated $carry
        return $carry;
    },
    // Start with an empty array (it is known as $carry in the callback function)
    array()
);

// $output contains the array you need
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$final = array();

foreach ($array_items as $item)
{
    $key = $item[0];
    $found_index = -1;

    for ($i=0; $i<count($final); $i++)
    {
        if ($key == $final[$i][0])
        {
            $found_index = $i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($found_index == -1)
    {
        $final_item = array();
        $final_item[0] = $key;
        $final_item[1] = $item[1];
        $final[] = $final_item;
    }
    else
    {
        $final[$found_index][1] .= ",".$item[1];
    }
}
```

We create a new array `$final`, and loop through your old array `$array_items`. For each item, we see if there is already an item in `$final` that has the same `[0]` index. If it doesn't exist, we create it and add the initial string to the `[1]` index. If it does exist, we just have to add the string onto the end of the `[1]` index.

Try it, substituting `$array_items` for whatever your array is called, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check my solution. It should work fine. I hope it will help you much.

```
$result = $passed_keys = $extended_arr = [];
foreach ($arr as $k => $value) {
    for($i = $k + 1; $i < count($arr); $i++){
        if ( $value[0] == $arr[$i][0] ){    // compare each array with rest subsequent arrays
            $key_name = $value[0];
            if (!array_key_exists($key_name, $result)){
                $result[$key_name] = $value[1] .",". $arr[$i][1];
            } else {
                if (!in_array($i, $passed_keys[$key_name])) {
                    $result[$key_name] .= ",". $arr[$i][1];

                }
            }
            $passed_keys[$key_name][] = $i; // memorizing keys that were passed
        }
    }
}
array_walk($result, function($v, $k) use(&$extended_arr){
    $extended_arr[] = [$k, $v];
});
```

The result is in `$extended_arr`

Answer (score 0):

My solution, creates a custom key which makes identifying the letter much easier. This removes the need to continuously iterate through each array, which can become a major resources hog.

```
<?php
$inital_array = array(
    array('A','XYZ'),
    array('B','ABC'),
    array('A','LMN'),
    array('B','PQR')
);

$concat_array = array();

foreach($inital_array as $a){
    $key = $a[0];

    if( !isset($concat_array[$key]) ){
        $concat_array[$key] = array($key,'');
    }

    $concat_array[$key][1] .= (empty($concat_array[$key][1]) ? '' : ',').$a[1];
}

$concat_array = array_values($concat_array);

echo '<pre>',print_r($concat_array),'</pre>';
```